# Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="documentation"]/div/div[2]/div/button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, javascriptexecutor

I am trying without success to click on a particular button using SELENIUM & JAVA but i am getting this error message:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="documentation"]/div/div[2]/div/button (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

That button has this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link add-row">Upload FILE</button>
```

The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="documentation"]/div/div[2]/div/div/button
```

I did this:

```
WebDriverWait wait10735 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        JavascriptExecutor executor3735  = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        WebElement elementCat4735=wait10735.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"documentation\"]/div/div[2]/div/button")));
```

What am i doing wrong in here?

Comment: What do you want to do after clicking the Upload button?

Comment: Hey @JaSON after clicking on that button another button is shown and it allows me to update a file, do you get me?

Comment: @JaSON is my XPATH correct?

Comment: It's hard to tell whether your XPath is correct since you use absolute XPath while shared HTML of button only... BTW don't use XPaths generated by browser dev tools or similar tools - they are not reliable and uninformative... Do you know that Selenium doesn't allow to operate with OS file uploading popup?

Comment: My code did work a few days ago but now it thrown that error message :/

Comment: mmm Maybe something changed in your page and now your absolute path is not valid. What if you try this xpath? `//button[text()='Upload FILE']` or `//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-link add-row']`

Comment: @JakyRuby hey pal, you mean this?: WebElement elementCat4735=wait10735.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Upload FILE']")));

Comment: @JakyRuby it worked!. I used: WebElement elementCat4735=wait10735.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Upload FILE']"))); Why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the xpath:

```
//button[text()='Upload FILE']
```

Should work.

### Why this happened?

The problem is that you were using the xpath:

```
xpath //*[@id=\"documentation\"]/div/div[2]/div/button
```

With that xpath what you are doing is:

1. Locating an element with `id="documentation"`
2. Then go to the first div child of that element
3. Then go to second div child of the previous div
4. Then go to the first div child of the previous div
5. Then go to the button

As you can see your final element (The button) is depending on several other parent elements to be located. Once one of those parent elements changes, your xpath is not valid anymore.

Is much better to locate your xpath based on the properties of your element itself, not on the elements that surround it.

In this case I used the text of the element.

I don't know if it is possible or not, but if it is possible, a good idea is to talk with developers for using ids for all the elements you will use with your automation. This is a team work!

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!. You said "In this case I used the text of the element.", which are the other ways to solve this?

Comment: You can use any attribute of the element like class as I said here: `//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-link add-row']`. Problem is that maybe there are some other elements that match with that criteria, so it is because of that is better to use ids, because there are usually uniques. Here a small guide how to locate elements by xpath: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: Can i ask you something, I have this XPATH from developer tools: //*[@id="Datatable_ReceiptListModel"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/i. What would it be the right way to use it?

Comment: Is it alright?: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Datatable_ReceiptListModel\"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/span/i")).click();

Comment: I need to see the html element to decide what xpath I would use.

Comment: <i class="fa fa-plus-square receipt-items-action plus"></i>

Comment: You could try `//i[class="fa fa-plus-square receipt-items-action plus"]` problem is that maybe a lot of elements match with that xpath, because it looks like the element is inside a table.